# Seeing an error when trying to use concatenation in Groovy

Tags: groovy, concatenation

I must not be escaping correctly in order to concatenate the variable with the rest of the string or something. I've checked the output of the new string and all looks good. See my code below.

```
import javax.crypto.Mac
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec
import java.security.InvalidKeyException


def emailAddress = '"test@test.com"'

def hmac_sha256(String secretKey, String data) {
    try {
        Mac mac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256")
        SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(secretKey.getBytes(), "HmacSHA256")
        mac.init(secretKeySpec)
        byte[] digest = mac.doFinal(data.getBytes())
        return digest
    } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Invalid key exception while converting to HMac SHA256")
    }
}

secret='1234'

// this will fail
def hash = hmac_sha256(secret, '/sf/v3/Accounts/GetByUser{"username":' + emailAddress + ',"employeesonly":false,"singleplane":false,"clientId":"someID"}')

// this will pass
def hash = hmac_sha256(secret, '/sf/v3/Accounts/GetByUser{"username":"test@test.com","employeesonly":false,"singleplane":false,"clientId":"someID"}')

encodedData = hash.encodeHex().toString()
println encodedData
```

I get an error on the one that will fail which says:

> Caught: java.lang.ClassFormatError: Illegal class name "test-groovy-temp$hmac_sha256" in class file test-groovy-temp$hmac_sha256
>   java.lang.ClassFormatError: Illegal class name "test-groovy-temp$hmac_sha256" in class file test-groovy-temp$hmac_sha256
>       at test-groovy-temp.run(test-groovy-temp.groovy:21)

This is only if I try to use concatenation.

Edited to remove typo.

Comment: There is some other error noticed and fixed, However, what you reported is not reproducible. See here [Demo](https://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/5091474953732096).

Comment: Thanks, you're right. The code looks sound outside of my dev setup. Not sure why I'm seeing the error still.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there is something wrong in my IDE/Compliler. I'm using IntelliJ IDEA for this project and maybe I've not configured it correctly. As Rao mentions, I also see that it's not repro elsewhere so I should be good.

Unless someone knows what's wrong with my IDE/Compiler by chance!